# Spring MVC forms: Dynamically add form select options in a one to many relationship

Tags: spring, forms, jsp

I have a spring form for a complex object that contains a List of email address objects within a One-To-One relationship object that contains a One-To-Many to email addresses. The use-case is as follows: user wants to add new email addresses to the existing ones in the form. This is done via a pop up window and a jQuery that appends a new option element inside the select statement as such:

```
<option value="0">new.email@address.com</option>
```

All the prepopulated options in the loaded form of course already have an ID set, such as:

```
<option value="1">existing.email@email.com</option>
```

**In my controller, the submitted form contains the ID field** (1 for the prepopulated object and 0 for the 'new' email address), **but the actual value in the form is null** - i.e. first@email.com is not submitted with the form and bound to the emailAddress field in the EmailAddress object:

This code:

```
List<EmailAddress> emailAddress = batchJob.getDestinationExtras().getMailsInternal();
for (EmailAddress e : emailAddress) {
    logger.info(e.getEmailAddressId() + " "+e.getEmailAddress());
}
```

Results into output:
1 null
0 null

This is not a problem for the existing objects because with the ID they can simply be retrieved from the database using hibernate either in the controller or already during the parse stage (I am using a formatter implementation for the EmailAddress object). But for the 'new' objects created dynamically by the user I have a problem because they do not yet exist in the database and thus the actual email address value can not be retrieved in this way.

**What could be a solution to this problem?**

The JSP tag is as follows:

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="destinationExtras.mailsInternal" id="internalMailsList">
    <form:options items="${internalMailsList}" itemValue="emailAddressId" itemLabel="emailAddress" />
</form:select>
```

The relevant parts of the objects involved below - omitting other fields and ID fields where not relevant:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="batchjob")
public class BatchJob {

    (...) id + other fields

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="destinationextrasid")
    private DestinationExtras destinationExtras;

    (...) getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="destinationextras")
public class DestinationExtras {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="emailaddressid")
    private List<EmailAddress> mailsInternal;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="emailaddresses")
public class EmailAddress {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_EMAILADDRESSID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_EMAILADDRESSID",sequenceName="SEQ_EMAILADDRESSID",allocationSize=1)
    private int emailAddressId;

    @Column(name="email_address")
    private String emailAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it goes wrong, think about the low-level HTTP protocol ... JQuery is very clever, so is Spring, but they can only communicate through HTTP ! And when submitting a form containing a `<select>` field, the only thing that is sent is the *value* of the selected option(s).

So if you want Spring to use the text of the new email, you could try to put it in the value of the `<option>` field, like :

```
<option value="new.email@address.com">new.email@address.com</option>
```

but I think you will have to change all the select to systematically use the text as value and change it also in your controller, to avoid mixing integer ids and texts. Your options would then be :

```
<form:options items="${internalMailsList}" itemValue="emailAddress" itemLabel="emailAddress" />
```

You can also just add a hidden field with the help of jQuery, with the email text as value and use it if you find a value of `0`, like that :

```
<input type="hidden" name="newmail" value="new.email@address.com"/>
<select ...>
    <option value="0">new.email@address.com</option>
```

Personnally, I would prefere that second way, but it really depends on you controller structure.

Comment: Both answers you suggest are correct. However, I was really hoping there would be another way, but as you mention this is about how the HTTP protocol works.